# Unpack Maven dependency into classes, keeping transitive dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, pom.xml

I am trying to unpack a maven dependency jar's contents into my `classes` folder, and at the same time include the transitive dependencies. I also don't want to unpack all of my project's dependencies. Only one would be good, even better if I could do this to a list of them. Found similar solutions but nothing addressing my exact issue.

Example Main Project Pom:

```
.
.
.
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.test.dep</groupId>
    <artifact>first-dependency</artifact>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.test.dep</groupId>
    <artifact>second-dependency</artifact>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
.
.
.
```

Example second-dependency Pom:

```
.
.
.
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.test.dep</groupId>
    <artifact>third-dependency</artifact>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.test.dep</groupId>
    <artifact>fourth-dependency</artifact>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
.
.
.
```

I want `second-dependency` to be unpacked into my `classes` folder nested under `target` and also want any of the artifacts (`third-dependency`, `fourth-dependency`) it depends on to still be included in my `lib` folder (not unpacked).

I tried the following (without including the the artifact in my dependencies):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>com.test.dep</groupId>
                        <artifactId>second-dependency</artifactId>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        <includes>**/*</includes>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And this did include the contents of `second-dependency` in my `classes` folder, but did not include `third-dependency` or `fourth-dependency` in my main projects `lib` directory.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use following plugin configuration, based on the described parameters of [dependency:unpack-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html), instead:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>unpack</id>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>unpack</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
        <includeArtifactIds>second-dependency</includeArtifactIds>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Im not sure about your use case.

But if you want to build jar, that sounds like a use case for the [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html). This plugin is able to package the classes and resources of the project itself as well as of a specified set of artifacts (dependencies) into one jar.

Just define the artifact itself ("${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}") and the "second dependency" to be included.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <artifactSet>
      <includes>
        <include>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}</include>
        <include>com.test.dep:second-dependency</include>
      </includes>
    </artifactSet>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: That sort of worked. What I really want to do though is include all dependencies in second-dependencies's pom, unpacking second-dependency into my classes folder, and at the same time not including the second-dependency.jar in my lib folder.